# How to fix 'Expected object of backend CUDA' when trying to apply_tfms in custom LearnerCallback

Tags: python, pytorch, fast-ai

Very new to machine learning, fastai, pytorch, and python, and I was trying to adapt a LearnerCallback to do transformations after manually modifying the images.  When I start my learn.fit_one_cycle, it's immediately interrupted as shown below:

I've tried sticking `.to(torch.device('cuda'))` everywhere I could think of

```
    #...
    def on_batch_begin(self, last_input, last_target, train, **kwargs):
        if not train: return

        #Get new input
        new_input = last_input.clone()
        new_target = last_target.clone()
        tfms = get_transforms(max_zoom=1.5)

        # modify the images here in some other way

        # apply_tfms
        for i in range(len(new_input)):            
            new_input[i] = Image(new_input[i]).apply_tfms(tfms[0]).data
            new_target[i] = Image(new_target[i]).apply_tfms(tfms[0], do_resolve=False).data
    #...
```

The 'apply_tfms' in the second to last line is the culprit in the traceback ending with:

```
    553     m[1,0] *= w/h
    554     c.flow = c.flow.view(-1,2)
--> 555     c.flow = torch.addmm(m[:2,2], c.flow,  m[:2,:2].t()).view(size)
    556     return c
    557 

RuntimeError: Expected object of backend CUDA but got backend CPU for argument #4 'mat1'
```

Is there a way I can apply the transforms within a LearnerCallback without getting that error, or an alternate method where I can get my LearnerCallback added with `learn.callback_fns.append` to run before apply_tfms runs the same transforms on both the modified input and target images?  I need pixel information from the target image to modify the input image.  I also need this process applied during training and validation.

If it makes any difference, I get the same error even if I don't modify the cloned images before apply_tfms.

Answer (score 0):

The problem that you have here is that some of your tensors are on CPU and some are on GPU.

You have to make sure that all your tensors are on the same device (either GPU or CPU depending on the situation) to get rid of this error. If I remember correctly, fastai `get_transforms` will create transforms that are supposed to be applied during data loading (and so on CPU), so you might want to take a look at the source of get_transforms and adapt it so it can be called on your tensor on GPU.(last_input should be on GPU if you're training on GPU).

Another solution is to apply those transforms during dataloading, in which case your data tensor will be on CPU.